# How to remove empty li in ul list using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>one</a></li>
    <li><a>two</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a>three</a></li>
    <li><a>four</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a>five</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to remove the `li` elements which are don't have any content (`<li></li>`).

How can I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('li').each(function(){
if($(this).html() == "" || typeof($(this).html())=="undefined")
{
    $(this).remove
}
})
```

I would suggest you to trim the html before the comparision, so that you do not end up counting:

```
<li>
</li>
```

as a non empty item.
To trim the html, simply add `.trim()` after `.html()` i.e:

```
if($(this).html().trim() == "" || typeof($(this).html().trim())=="undefined")
```

Comment: this is the way I would have chosen too but would you mind explaining why you added `typeof($(this).html())=="undefined"`?

Comment: To prevent possible troubles with IE.

Answer (score 8):

With just a jQuery selector

```
$("ul li:empty").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acS9A/

Answer (score 2):

Untested so let me know if it doesn't work for you.

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var li = $(this);
    if (li.html() == '') {
      li.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: The `html` method is a method, not a property.

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to use the [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector:

```
$('li:empty').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/4yf2t/

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('li').each(
         function(){
             if($(this).html().trim()==''){$(this).remove();}
         }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` method to run a custom function to find the elements to remove:

```
$('ul li').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '' }).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('li').filter(function() { return !$(this).html(); }).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li:empty').remove();
//OR
$('ul li').filter(function() {return $(this).text()​​​​​​​ == '';}).remove();​
```